# How to Transpose with Zip python...What is the explanation?

Tags: python, matrix, tuples, transpose, python-zip

I just learnt this trick of how to use zip to transpose data from a m-by-n matrix to a n-by-m matrix from the Udacity Intro to Python course. While I get how it works, I am finding it hard to get an explanation of this process. It would be great if someone can help out.

```
data = ((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11))
data_transpose = tuple(zip(*data))
print(data_transpose)
```

Outputs:

```
((0, 3, 6, 9), (1, 4, 7, 10), (2, 5, 8, 11))
```

Comment: `zip` takes an arbitrary amount of iterables and aggregates the corresponding elements.

Comment: `zip(*data)` is effectively `zip((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11))`, If you understand basically what `zip` does, than that should be enough additional information…